# Нужно ли поставить запятую перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

Задумалась над предложением: "Он хотел подхватить стакан и сам свалился с кафедры". Является ли определительное местоимение "сам" подлежащим и, таким образом, здесь две основы или одна? Уважаемые филологи, выскажите ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Я не филолог, но попробую. Запятая не нужна, вторая часть не является самостоятельным предложением. А вот обосновать — это посложнее будет.

Во-первых, спасибо за хороший вопрос.
Во-вторых, оговорюсь, что здесь речь идёт именно о местоимении в несубстантивированом значении (ибо есть ещё "сам" — начальник, босс). Еще одно, ныне совершенно уже неупотребимое значение, сохранившееся только в архаичных формах типа "сам-друг", я просто опускаю. И в третьих, тут надо иметь в виду, что грамматика ведь в принципе не запрещает считать вторую часть самостоятельным предложением даже в отсутствии слова "сам". Если уж не в такой форме, то в первом лице настоящего времени ("Я подхватываю стакан и валюсь с кафедры"). Только вся штука в том, что такие предложения вне контекста обычно лишены смысла — и обычно их опускают из рассмотрения. Поэтому всё-таки придётся считать "сам свалился" продолжением первой части, а не самостоятельным предложением.

Из всего этого получается, что "сам" в принципе не может быть самостоятельным подлежащим. В противном случае ваша вторая часть была бы частью двусоставного предложения — и таким образом должна была бы иметь законченный смысл даже в отсутствии первой. Что, как легко убедиться, места не имеет.

Comment: @Третийглаз не увлекайтесь, пожалуйста. "Сам-друг" пишется через дефис.

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение. Никогда не слышал.

Answer (score 1):

Простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, запятая не нужна.
Слово **сам** здесь по смыслу, на мой взгляд, синонимично слову "тоже": *стакан падал. он хотел его подхватить и тоже упал(свалился).*

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, но вполне возможно тире как знак, указывающий на неожиданность, противоположность действий:

*Он хотел подхватить стакан - и сам свалился с кафедры. Ср.: Он хотел подхватить стакан, НО сам свалился с кафедры.*

[Тире при однородных членах](https://7lafa.com/pageanswer.php?id=33579)  Может ставиться тире между однородными сказуемыми при указании на внезапность, неожиданность действия или быструю смену событий, при указании на следствие, содержащееся во втором сказуемом (даже при наличии союза «и»): Скакун мой призадумался — и прыгнул; Комар изловчился — жиг его в нос; Бегу туда — и вас обоих нахожу.